# Convert pandas dataframe with dictionary objects into polars dataframe with object type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-polars

I have a pandas dataframe with a column of dictionaries. I want to convert this to a polars dataframe with dtype `polars.Object`, which apparently wraps arbitrary Python objects. I am unable to figure out how to do this.

Consider this code:

```
>>> df = pandas.DataFrame({ "the_column": [{ "key" : 123 }, { "foo" : 456 }, { "bar" : 789 }]})
>>> df
     the_column
0  {'key': 123}
1  {'foo': 456}
2  {'bar': 789}
>>> polars.from_pandas(df)
shape: (3, 1)
┌─────────────────┐
│ the_column      │
│ ---             │
│ struct[3]       │
╞═════════════════╡
│ {null,null,123} │
│ {null,456,null} │
│ {789,null,null} │
└─────────────────┘
```

As you can see, by default, polars tries to convert the dictionaries to arrow structs. This is not what I want, since the keys are not the same for each object. I want them to stay as Python objects. The `schema_overrides` feature does something, but not what I want either:

```
>>> polars.from_pandas(df, schema_overrides = {'the_column': polars.Object })
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'cannot convert object to arrow', /Users/runner/work/polars/polars/polars/polars-core/src/datatypes/dtype.rs:232:26
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 498, in wrapper
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 433, in wrapper
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/convert.py", line 486, in from_pandas
    include_index=include_index,
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 433, in wrapper
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/dataframe/frame.py", line 642, in _from_pandas
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/utils.py", line 433, in wrapper
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/construction.py", line 1410, in pandas_to_pydf
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/construction.py", line 1242, in arrow_to_pydf
    schema, schema_overrides=schema_overrides
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/polars/internals/construction.py", line 577, in _post_apply_columns
    column_names,  # type: ignore[return-value]
pyo3_runtime.PanicException: cannot convert object to arrow
```

How can I accomplish what I want here?

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

You don't.

### Longer Answer

As stated in the [book](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/datatypes.html?highlight=Object#data-types), `Object` data has limited support. Here, you're bumping up against one of those limits because a collection of python dictionaries is not a data type that is in the Arrow standard, at least not without a bunch of customization. Moreover, with a column of python dicts, there is not a lot you can "do" with the data in a performant manner anyway.

If you want to use polars (and you should, it's pretty cool!) then I'd suggest you'd be better off simply re-structuring your data into a format that is able to play nice with the (column-based) Arrow data structures that polars will handle without issue.

For example, in your case you've got only a single key-value pair in each python dict. Let's assume this is always true, then you could create column `"key"` that contains the key, and another column `"value"` that holds the value. Information loss is exactly zero between the two structures, but in the suggested two-column version you can now do whatever you like with the resulting frame.

```py
(
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "the_column": pl.Series(
                [
                    {"key": 123},
                    {"foo": 456},
                    {"bar": 789},
                ],
                dtype=pl.Object
            ),
        }
    )
    .select(
        pl.col("the_column")
        .apply(lambda x: list(x.keys()))
        .arr.get(0)
        .alias("key"),
        pl.col("the_column")
        .apply(lambda x: list(x.values()))
        .arr.get(0)
        .alias("value"),
    )
)

shape: (3, 2)
┌─────┬───────┐
│ key ┆ value │
│ --- ┆ ---   │
│ str ┆ i64   │
╞═════╪═══════╡
│ key ┆ 123   │
│ foo ┆ 456   │
│ bar ┆ 789   │
└─────┴───────┘
```

Or something similar, depending on what your actual data looks like.