# Polars conversion error going from Python to Rust with pyo3

Tags: python, dataframe, rust, rust-polars, pyo3

Related to the solution proposed in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75827086/convert-pandas-dataframe-with-dictionary-objects-into-polars-dataframe-with-obje/75827315#75827315).

This code creates a polars dataframe of python dictionaries. In Python land, everything is fine. The code fails when we `extract` to Rust land.

```rust
use pyo3::prelude::*;
use pyo3_polars::*;

let code = r#"
import polars as pl
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ "the_column": [{ "key" : 123 }, { "foo" : 456 }, { "bar" : 789 }]})        
schema = pl.from_pandas(df.head(1)).schema | {"the_column": pl.Object}
result = pl.DataFrame(df.to_dict("records"), schema=schema)
"#;

Python::with_gil(|py| {
    let globals = py.import("builtins").unwrap().dict();
    py.run(code, Some(globals), None).unwrap();
    let result = globals.get_item("result").unwrap();
    let PyDataFrame(_df) = result.extract().unwrap();
});
```

The error is:

```
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidOperation(Owned("Cannot create polars series from FixedSizeBinary(8) type"))'
```

Polars is in `Cargo.toml` with:

```
polars = { version = "~0.27.2", features = ["object", "dtype-full"] }
```